# Setting format of setters & getters in Scala case classes

Tags: scala, encapsulation

In Scala, I have a case class:

```
case class MonthSelectionInfo(monthSelection: MonthSelection.Value, customMonth:Int = 0, customYear:Int = 0) {

 def this(monthSelection: MonthSelection.Value) = {
   this(monthSelection, 0, 0)
 }
}


object MonthSelection extends Enumeration {
  type MonthSelection = Value

  val LastMonth, ThisMonth, NextMonth, CustomMonth = Value
}
```

When I have an instance of the case class, I have to use

myMonthSelectionInfo.monthSelection

and

myMonthSelectionInfo.eq(newMonthSelection)

to get & set the MonthSelection instance contained within.

Is there any nice Scala way to format the getter & setter to look more like regular Java POJOs? e.g.

```
myMonthSelectionInfo.setMonthSelection(newMonthSelection)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is [`@BeanProperty`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/reflect/BeanProperty.html) annotation to generate getters and setters for fields.

```
case class MonthSelectionInfo(@reflect.BeanProperty var monthSelection: MonthSelection.Value)

scala> val ms = MonthSelectionInfo(MonthSelection.LastMonth)
ms: MonthSelectionInfo = MonthSelectionInfo(LastMonth)

scala> ms.setMonthSelection(MonthSelection.ThisMonth)

sscala> ms.getMonthSelection
res4: MonthSelection.Value = ThisMonth
```

Comment: Note that this generate additional getters and setters. It does not remove Scala's default getters and setters.

Comment: Shouldn't case classes be immutable ?

Answer (score 0):

In object oriented programming, getters and setters are something that most would agree have some real world benefits. Unfortunately, they can sometimes be annoying to write. They usually do not consist of a lot of code , but when you have the write the same thing over and over and over it gets old really fast. In my experience, most getters and setters are very much alike so it stands to reason that there must be a “better” way to accomplish the same result.

This [link](http://www.dustinmartin.net/2009/10/getters-and-setters-in-scala/) may help you.

Comment: Hi! Obsolete link?

Answer (score 0):

We can use `@BeanProperty` in scala 2.11.

```scala
    import scala.beans.BeanProperty
    case class Employee(@BeanProperty var id: Long, @BeanProperty var name: String, @BeanProperty var age: Long)
```